# Executing Azure SQL stored procedure from php

Tags: php, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure on an Azure SQL database.  I'm trying to run the stored procedure from PHP but I'm not sure how to execute it.

Here is my attempt:

```
$playerQuery="{dbo.player_strength_update '$player'}";
$playerResult=sqlsrv_query($conn, $playerQuery) or die("Could not run stored procedure");
```

It consistently fails with the die result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem after a day of banging my head on the wall.

I found that my stored procedure was all sorts of wrong.  But my original question was to verify that I was even executing the procedure call properly.  Below is the exact PHP syntax I'm using in case it helps anyone else:

```
$playerQuery="dbo.player_strength_update '$player'";
$playerResult=sqlsrv_query($conn, $playerQuery) or die("Could not run stored procedure");
```